# How to work with transclusion in Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs

I am trying hard to understand transclusion and figured out that 
`dynamic content can be projected into <ng-content> block`. That's the basic idea, I suppose.

I was following `how to build tabs component in Angular 2+`.
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html

Have some basic doubts to be clarified.

So, in the `app` component's `template`:

```
  template:`
          <tabs>
            <tab tabTitle="Tab 1" >Tab 1 Content</tab>
            <tab tabTitle="Tab 2">Tab 2 Content</tab>
          </tabs>
          `
```

**So, It is Tab component inside Tabs Component and Each Tab component has some data content I guess which needs to be projected as ng-content.**

Now, In Tab component, `template` looks like :

```
  template:`
          <div [hidden]="!active" class="pane">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
          </div>
          `
```

This is understandable.
What I am not getting clearly is, how `Tabs Component` looks:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
    template:`
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li *ngFor="let tab of tabComponents">{{tab.title}}</li>
            </ul>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            `
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit,AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabComponents:QueryList<TabComponent>;
```

**Why** `<ng-content></ng-content>` **here needs to be used?**
**The dynamic content is inside tab component, so** `<ng-content></ng-content>` **in tab's template makes sense, why is it there in 
tabs component's template?**

Please clarify the basics.

Comment: Perhaps to pass prepared tabs to be shown in addition to these generated by `*ngFor`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry could not get your point. Could you please elaborate on it with simpler terms or examples would also be great.

Comment: Have you tried without `<ng-content></ng-content>`? I don't see why you would need it. Why do you think you do? Your code doesn't show how you use it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Actually yes, I also don't get what it does. I was going through the document provided in my question and got stuck there while trying to practice the same.

Comment: I don't want to read the whole document. In short. If you have `<app-tabs><h1>some title</h1></app-tabs>`, then `<h1>some title</h1>` will be shown where your `TabsComponent` has the `<ng-content></ng-content>` element.